# I need help to move div when on Key Code 39 and 37

Tags: javascript

Guys, I have a div, when clicking on it, it is going right, 
Now I need help, to make it go right when pressing Key Code 39, and left when Pressing key 37.

```js
 myDiv.onclick = function() {
      animate(function(timePassed) {
        myDiv.style.left = timePassed / 5 + 'px';
      }, 3000);
    };

    // Рисует функция draw
    // Продолжительность анимации duration
    function animate(draw, duration) {
      var start = performance.now();

      requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
        // определить, сколько прошло времени с начала анимации
        var timePassed = time - start;

        console.log(time, start)
          // возможно небольшое превышение времени, в этом случае зафиксировать конец
        if (timePassed > duration) timePassed = duration;

        // нарисовать состояние анимации в момент timePassed
        draw(timePassed);

        // если время анимации не закончилось - запланировать ещё кадр
        if (timePassed < duration) {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

      });
    }
```

```css
 #myDiv {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 150px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add keydown event listener.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  switch (e.which || e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      // go left code
      alert("left");
      break;
    case 39:
      // go right code
      alert("right");
      break;
  }
});
```

[Here is an example with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/ubr3bbao/1/), just add your animation logic to cases...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code that will detect that a key is pressed

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // use e.keyCode
};
```

In the following snippet I used the `keyCode 97` which is the letter A

You can replace it with the key codes you need and then call your `animate` function

```js
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  // use e.keyCode
  //if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 37) {
  if(e.keyCode == 97){
    animate(function(timePassed) {
      myDiv.style.left = timePassed / 5 + 'px';
    }, 3000);
  }
};

function animate(draw, duration) {
  var start = performance.now();

  requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
    // определить, сколько прошло времени с начала анимации
    var timePassed = time - start;

    console.log(time, start)
      // возможно небольшое превышение времени, в этом случае зафиксировать конец
    if (timePassed > duration) timePassed = duration;

    // нарисовать состояние анимации в момент timePassed
    draw(timePassed);

    // если время анимации не закончилось - запланировать ещё кадр
    if (timePassed < duration) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

  });
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150px;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```